# Remove a variable value from the list of possible values

Tags: r

I am using the dataset that can be accessed with the following command - `load(url("http://bit.ly/dasi_gss_data"))`

When I run the query `table(gss$premarsx)`, it returns a column called Other with count 0. When I plot a graph of the same variable (premarsx), there is a column Other with zero height. Is there a way to remove the variable value Other from the variable definition so that it does not appear in the results of any queries/plots?

Comment: `table(factor(gss$premarsx))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass it through the `factor()` function to have it pick up the present levels:

```
gss$premarsx <- factor(gss$premarsx)
```